# How to redirect page to another page in different folder?

Tags: php

I'm currently using this code `header("Location: ");` for redirection but was unable to redirect to different page in different folder.

How would I do it to redirect to another page in another folder? Lets consider the folder is in my desktop `C:\Users\Jozev\Desktop\`

Comment: You can't redirect to something outside your server document root.

Comment: Oh my, that would be a problem. Anyway, thank you very much for the information.

Comment: Did that solve your problem? If so I'm more than happy to write an answer you can accept.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, was cracking my head trying to solve the problem for me to connect to folders. How about in `forms` can I use the `action` to redirect to another page in another folder?

Comment: Found my solution. Sorry for wasting your time. Terribly sorry and thank you very much for the information just now. Have a good day ahead !